# child node removing from treeview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I need to remove particular child nodes from their parent in treeview control.

For example:

**Before Login**

```
home 

 -register

 -login

 -pdf
```

**After login**

```
home

 -pdf
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be like...

```
//This will remove login
TreeNode tn = TreeView1.FindNode("home/login"); // find particular node
TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Remove(tn); // then remove from TreeView
//This will remove register
tn = TreeView1.FindNode("home/register"); // find particular node
TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Remove(tn); // then remove from TreeView
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding child node in parent node programmatically:

TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("login");

tn.NavigateUrl = "/home/login";

TreeView1.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(tn);